# Unicode Characters in HTTP Get request

Tags: c#, web-services, unicode, get

I have a C# REST Webservice exposing the following method:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet
            (
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            UriTemplate = "/Files?id={ID}"
            )
        ]
        Stream GetFilesForID(string ID);
```

This method fetches the information from database, based on ID specified by user. This ID can have chinese characters in it.

My implementation for the method:

```
public Stream GetFilesForID(string ID)
{
    ID = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ID));

    // and connect to database and
    // stream back the list.
}
```

"ID" still does not contain chinese characters in it. It looks like: `ã³ãã«-å¤ªé`

I have client code, that is written in C++ and calling this REST Webservice method, using winHTTP library. I have tested this using fiddler too, but i get the same result i.e. chinese characters are showing as weird characters.

If I have a "POST" method, with the request body having unicode characters, my webservice method gets the request body without any problem. I do not even have to do anything like this: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));`

What am I missing here? Do i need to do anything else before sending the HTTP GET request?

Answer (score 2):

All characters C# can handle are are Unicode characters.

Only some characters are valid unescaped in URIs. More are allowed in IRIs, but we want a URI here.

In the query portion, you should always use `Uri.EscapeDataString`. Not only will it deail with Chinese:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("孫子兵法 孫武")
//returns %E5%AD%AB%E5%AD%90%E5%85%B5%E6%B3%95%20%E5%AD%AB%E6%AD%A6
```

But also problematic English and other languages:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("A naïve approach = trouble waiting + bugs & complaints!")
//A%20na%C3%AFve%20approach%20%3D%20trouble%20waiting%20%2B%20bugs%20%26%20complaints!
```

Incidentally, `ID = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ID))` is equivalent to `ID = ID`, because it undoes exactly what it first does. That you saw mojibake instead of the source Chinese string was something else screwing with it later.